# find the proper number of shards in elasticsearch

Tags: node.js

I've started working with `elasticsearch`. I don't have any cluster nor shard nor replica. I just have some node that are not in a cluster.

First, I want to improve search for my site with `elasticsearch`. Now imagine I have 4 nodes,I want to know how many shards I should have in only one node ?

I don't want the default 5 shards. My requirements are the following :

- qps=50
- size of document=300k
- size of ram for one node is 5G

How many shards are needed in one node in `elasticsearch` when we have no cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to set the number of shardes relatively to number of nodes, meaning,if you have 1 node, you need 1 or two shardes, but it's also depend of the number of the documents , it's need to be plus minus 1 million documents per shard.
In conclusion, use one of two shardes, but if you have more than 2 millions documents, you need more nodes